# CSS error on jboss console

Tags: css, jboss

I am getting the below CSS error on the Jboss console.

**Error in @media rule. (Invalid token "and". Was expecting one of: , , .)**

This is the particular CSS class related to the above error.

*@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {*

Please let me know why this error is thrown or is there any syntax error on this class.

Below is the entire CSS class

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
@supports (not (-ms-accelerator:true)) {
select.form-control{
    line-height:28px!important;     
    -webkit-appearance: menulist-button !important;     
}
 } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your CSS? Most likely you didn't close it or forgot to completely nest something along the way (probably forgot a semicolon or something).

Comment: Hi Shaun, Have added the rest of the CSS, please have a look and let me know your thoughts.